# How to show Stacktrace of java.util.concurrent.CompletionException (Using JavaFX)

Tags: java, maven, javafx

I am developing a Java Library that is used in a Java GUI that is based on JavaFX.
During manual testing, I can produce the following Error, printed to the console - the GUI hangs, but the window stays open:

```
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load xxx.xxx.xxx.main.tab.editor.workspace.canvas.canvas
```

No Stacktrace, no line number, no class that caused the exception, nothing that I can work with.

How do I get a stacktrace for this?

I tried the following things already:

- Instead of running the packaged jar with `java -jar Application.jar`, I tried just running the main class with `mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="xxx.xxx.xxx.App"`
- I tried using the verbose flag: `java -verbose -jar Application.jar`
- From other threads, I tried the `-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow` flag

Nothing changed the error message to be anything else than this single line.

Edit: The exception is not caught in the project's own code, however it might be caught by a library - so I hope maybe this is something done by JavaFX itself and there is a way to fix it? I guess JavaFX should be the main source of concurrency in the project.

Comment: It looks like that message is coming from a catch block which does something like `catch (Exception exc) { System.out.println(exc.getMessage()); }` (or equivalently `System.out.println(exc);`). If you have such catch blocks in your code, replace them with `catch (Exception exc) { exc.printStackTrace();}` (or, if these are unchecked exceptions, maybe just remove the `try`-`catch` entirely). If there is third-party library code that is suppressing the stack trace in that way, then there is little you can do (though that is a strong sign the library is not good enough quality to use).

Comment: Thank you! I checked my own code and found no catches that catch the thrown exceptions, and all catch statements either print the stacktrace or open an error window. So I can only hope that the error comes from a catch in JavaFX and not one of the smaller dependencies and there is someone out there who can help disable them...

Comment: I'm pretty sure JavaFX does not do this. JavaFX is essentially single-threaded.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found the culprit, it is indeed the **something JavaFX-y catching the error**:

The class from the exception is a JavaFX...module *(? component? whatever, it has a CanvasView and CanvasPresenter class and is in a folder that contains all the ressources like .fxml and .properties files, and it is really hard to google the basic concept)*

The exception is thrown in the `CanvasPresenter` `initialize` method (`CanvasPresenter` implements the `Initializable` interface), and there I could wrap the offending code in a `try {...} catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}` and get more information.

Comment: There is no `CanvasView` or `CanvasPresenter` class in JavaFX, as far as I know. What are the fully-qualified class names of the classes you are referring to?

Comment: Those are classes implemented in the project. Source code I have control over. Sorry for not making that explicit - I just added those names because they showed up in the error message (fully qualified class names are `xxx.xxx.xxx.main.tab.editor.workspace.canvas.<Class>`, I think), so people can make the connection.

Comment: This also happened in JavaFx 11, from which I now upgraded, so I will see if this will happen again in JavaFx 17.

Comment: I doubt upgrading will make any difference. Now you have the stack trace you can read it and figure out what you're doing wrong.